# Why does docker IP exhaustion happen when I have less than the limit of 256 on the stack?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a swarm that currently has 135 containers running on the stack my-stack, this has been down from 156 as there was continuous problems with IP  exhaustion but because the subnet is configured to be /24 in theory it should have had 100 IP's available to use.  Doing a docker system prune --all on all of the docker nodes did not bring back any available IP's to use.

On one instance one of the docker nodes went down due to a memory issue and due to IP exhaustion some service's containers failed to come back online.  The node had to be removed from the swarm and I had to delete the contents of the /var/lib/docker/swarm to rejoin the node back to the swarm.  After I did this applications where able to allocate IP's to that node.

How does IP allocation work with docker stacks and is there a way check for IP's that are allocated to the containers and how far away IP exhaustion is from happening?  As after I added the node back into the swarm I did not expect that it would help the IP exhaustion problem.

docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   9ee9f40
 Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:17:20 2018
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.1-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.5
  Git commit:   9ee9f40
  Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:15:30 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

Ubuntu version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Answer (score 2):

I can provide a workaround to this:

create a larger network:

```
docker network create --driver overlay --subnet=192.168.0.0/16 new_net
```

update your `stack`:

```
docker service update MYSERVICE --network-rm old_net --network-add new_net
```

if you are really out of `IPs` , you should see something like this in `daemon` logs:

> level=error msg="task allocation failure" error="failed to allocate
>   network IP for task taskid network networkid : could not find an
>   available IP" module=node level=error msg="Failed to allocate network
>   resources for node nodeid" error="could not find an available IP"
>   module=node node.id=nodeid

I think that `docker` need sometime to lease un-used `IPs` , so using a larger network will help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

In my environment, we solved this by creating more networks and linking to traefik, so we could use another 256 available addresses for each network created;
Example:

**traefik-docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'
networks:
  webgateway:
    driver: overlay
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet : 192.168.1.0/24
  webgateway_2:
    driver: overlay
    ipam:
      driver: default
  webgateway_3:
    driver: overlay
    ipam:
      driver: default
  webgateway_4:
    driver: overlay
    ipam:
      driver: default

services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.1.3"
    command:
      - "--ping=true"
      - "--ping.entryPoint=ping"
      - "--providers.docker.swarmMode=true"
      - "--providers.docker.network=traefik_webgateway"
      - "--providers.docker.network=traefik_webgateway_2"
      - "--providers.docker.network=traefik_webgateway_3"
      - "--providers.docker.network=traefik_webgateway_4"
      - "--providers.file.directory=/configuration"
      - "--providers.file.watch=true"
      - "--entryPoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entryPoints.web.forwardedHeaders.insecure"
      - "--entryPoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--entryPoints.websecure.forwardedHeaders.insecure"
      - "--entryPoints.ping.address=:8082"
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--metrics=true"
      - "--metrics.prometheus=true"
      - "--accesslog=true"
    networks:
      - webgateway
      - webgateway_2
      - webgateway_3
      - webgateway_4
    ports:
      - "443:433"
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8082:8082"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /root/traefik/configuration/:/configuration/
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
      mode: global
      placement:
       constraints:
         - node.role == manager
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=false
```

**my api.yml 1:**

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  traefik_webgateway:
    external: true

services:
  web:
    image: myservicename
    command: ["node", "server"]
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Sao_Paulo
    networks:
      - traefik_webgateway
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
      labels:
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_webgateway"
        - "traefik.http.routers.myservicename.rule=Host(`service.example.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.myservicename.entrypoints=web"
        - "traefik.http.routers.myservicename.service=myservicename"
        - "traefik.http.services.myservicename.loadbalancer.server.port=3335"
```

**my front.yml after 256 services:**

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  traefik_webgateway_2:
    external: true

services:
  web:
    image: myfront
    command: ["node", "server"]
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Sao_Paulo
    networks:
      - traefik_webgateway_2
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
      labels:
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_webgateway_2"
        - "traefik.http.routers.myfront.rule=Host(`myfront.example.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.myfront.entrypoints=web"
        - "traefik.http.routers.myfront.service=myfront"
        - "traefik.http.services.myfront.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
```